# UIView.animateWithDuration immediately after app launch

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview, uiviewanimation

I have this weird problem, I call UIView.animateWithDuration in viewDidAppear of my app's initial View Controller, but the animation seems to jump (it becomes visible somewhere halfway). The only workaround I found is to add a delay before starting the animation. I'd love to understand why this happens and if there's a better solution than the delay.

To try it yourself, create a single view app, then add the method below in ViewController.swift (Xcode debugger slows the app a bit, to simulate real conditions, stop and launch the app from the device or simulator):

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let redSquare = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50))
    redSquare.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    redSquare.center = view.center

    view.addSubview(redSquare)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5) { () -> Void in
        var newFrame = redSquare.frame
        newFrame.origin.y -= 200
        redSquare.frame = newFrame
    }
}
```

The red square is supposed to start translating from the center of the screen to somewhere up top, but it's as if the animation starts but the app is not ready to display it yet, so you see the red square starting it's translation above the center.

EDIT: Added call to viewDidAppear in example (does not solve the problem though).

Comment: Not sure if that's what the problem is, but have you tried calling super.viewDidAppear before you do the animations ?

Comment: I actually already do that, I just forgot it in the example.

Comment: I copied and pasted your code to an empty project.It worked really well for me as you wanted it to be.